# Round-tripping Python's ElementTree from/tostring drops namespaces

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I've got a base XML string that I want to build off of, so the first thing I do is parse the XML string into an etree.

However, it looks like the other namespaces "d" and "m" are being ignored. I can successfully parse the string into an XML `Element`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
BASE = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<feed
  xml:base="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
>
</feed>
"""
a = ET.fromstring(BASE)
# <Element '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}feed' at 0x000002264B03F778>
```

But when we convert *back* to string, we drop the "d" and "m" namespaces:

```
ET.tostring(a)
# Formatted manually for StackOverflow
# b'<ns0:feed
#    xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
#    xml:base="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/">
# </ns0:feed>'
```

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that unused namespaces are dropped. If you change your `BASE` to something like this:

```
BASE = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<feed
  xml:base="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
>
  <m:properties>
    <d:Id>NuGetTest</d:Id>
  </m:properties>
</feed>
"""
```

You'll see the missing namespaces:

```
>>> et.tostring(a)
b'<ns0:feed
   xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
   xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
   xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
   xml:base="http://localhost:40221/nuget">
     <ns1:properties>
       <ns2:Id>NuGetTest</ns2:Id>
     </ns1:properties>
</ns0:feed>'
```

Note that the namespaces change: `d` becomes `ns2`, `m` becomes `ns1`. I'm not sure how Python does this, but it looks like it's just based on which is used first.

Comment: If you want to keep the original namespace prefixes, you can use the `register_namespace` function. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace

Comment: Thanks, I did see that in the docs but it wasn't clear to me what it would actually do. I guess I should have tested it out first...